# What is the difference between faulty coordination and faulty parallelism?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the two errors ? 
I've tried to understand the difference between them , but none of the sources helps .

Comment: I can vaguely guess what your question is about, but without examples (or quoting the source) I find it impossible to answer. Neither of these phrases is a well-established term in my experience.

Comment: Faulty coordination is when I trip over something and wreck my shoulder.  I ended up parallel to the ground, so I don't think there's any problem with parallelism.

Answer (score 2):

**Faulty coordination** is joining two clauses in such a way that the meaning is illogical:

> The iPhone is the best smart phone, and I bought one.

This should be one of

> Because the iPhone is the best smart phone, I bought one.
>   The iPhone is the best smart phone, so I bought one.

**Faulty parallelism** is mixing different syntactic structures when they should be the same:

> I enjoy reading, writing, and to calculate.

which should be

> I enjoy readying, writing, and calculating.

Answer (score -1):

You can have faulty coordination when constituents of unlike categories are coordinated.  E.g., in

> I have two red cars, and I have read many books. -> *I have two red cars and read many books.

the noun phrase "two red cars" and the participle phrase "read many books" cannot be coordinated, because they have different grammatical properties.

Other than this problem of coordinating unlike categories, there is no such thing as faulty parallelism that prevents coordination.  The grammatical error that comes closest, I suppose, is the case where a phrase from which something has been extracted is coordinated with a phrase of like category, but without anything extracted.  This is a violation of Ross's Coordinate Structure Constraint.  E.g.,

> Joyce had something and got married.  *Guess what Joyce had and got married.

where a verb phrase "had" from which the direct object has been extracted is coordinated with a verb phrase "got married" with nothing extracted.  The problem here is, actually, faulty coordination, as Ross later showed in his paper "Guess Who", since if the entire coordinate structure is elided, the result is grammatical:

> Joyce had something and got married.  Guess what.

The correct solution to the puzzle was proposed by Gerald Gazdar: the verb phrase from which the object has been removed has a different grammatical category from an ordinary verb phrase, and that's why the two cannot be coordinated.

So even this is not really a problem of parallelism, but rather trying to coordinate phrases of different categories.

Comment: *I was tired and went to bed.* That coordinates an adjective and a verb phrase. Two different categories, so is it ungrammatical?

Comment: @JimReynolds It's grammatical, but both "tired" and "went to bed" are verb phrases.  Not only can a predicate adjective be coordinated with another verb phrase, but it can also be elided under identity with a preceding verb phrase: "She was tired, and I was, too."

Comment: I think it's an adjective in my example sentence, and in that sentence can't be a verb in anyone's grammar. If *tired* were a verb, then could we say, *I'm sick and tired*, setting the adjective *sick* in coordination with the "verb" (as you say, I think) *tired?* In fact, we can coordinate elements that belong to different sentence constituent categories. Thus, we need a more comprehensive way to explain what cannot be coordinated. I don't pretend that I can do it, mind you, but I think that part of your answer misses the mark.

Comment: @JimReynolds, of course "tired" is an adjective in this construction.  The verb phrase consists of that adjective.  That's what predicate adjectives are.  Verb phrases do not have to have verbs, any more than noun phrases have to have nouns.